# How To Save data in Two Table in mvc4

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two table

1- P_Product

2- P_Imagepath

I want to store Inputs Data In P_Product Table and on the basis of the Id Of the 1st table. I want to store images into The P_Imagepath table with P_Product Id.

Here I tried but it shows some error

> In Foreach loop it shows "A new expression is requires (),[],{}after
>   type" and in "item" its shows cannot imlicitly convert type
>   System.web.HttpPostedFileBase to string

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(P_Product p_product,List<HttpPostedFileBase> Base)
        {      
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.P_Product.Add(p_product);                
                db.SaveChanges();
                P_Product product = db.P_Product.LastOrDefault();
                int p = product.Id;
                List<P_ImagePath>images=new List<P_ImagePath>
                foreach(var item in Base)
                {
                    P_ImagePath image=new P_ImagePath();
                    image.P_Id=p;
                    image.ImagePath=item;
                    images.Add(image);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Cat_Id = new SelectList(db.P_Category, "Id", "Name", p_product.Cat_Id);           
            return View(p_product);
        }
```

Comment: what is the error you got ?

Comment: In Foreach loop it shows "A new expression is requires (),[],{}after type" and in "item" its shows cannot imlicitly convert type System.web.HttpPostedFileBase to string

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: try base[item] instead of item

Comment: base[item] not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//this line has syntax error - missing "();"
//correct form: List<P_ImagePath>images=new List<P_ImagePath>();
List<P_ImagePath>images=new List<P_ImagePath>
```

Your *image.ImagePath* is probably string (it is), and *item* is item from Base list, which means that item is of type *HttpPostedFileBase* (method parameter), so you cannot convert that to string.

What you can do is to find path of that file from *item*. So, try with this:

```
...
foreach(var item in Base)
{
    P_ImagePath image=new P_ImagePath();
    image.P_Id=p;
    image.ImagePath= Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
    images.Add(image);
}
```

Comment: After using this changes intomy code its not working its showing error like   `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'UploadRecords.Models.P_Product LastOrDefault[P_Product](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[UploadRecords.Models.P_Product])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`